# Are QML signals constrained by their hierarchy? See Loader Example

Tags: android, qt

I have a main.qml file which loads two component rectangles defined in separate component files called ImageRed.qml and ImageBlue.qml.  Both Red and Blue components have a button that raises the same signal that a Loader is supposed to respond to.  That Loader replaces the ImageBlue rectangle with a third component called ImageGreen.The problem is that the loader only responds to the button on ImageBlue and not to the same signal that the button on ImageRed raises. Why?

//main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

Item {
    id: imageselector
    width: 360
    height: 500
    Rectangle {
        id: background
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        color: "lightblue"
        LoaderSwitch {}
        ImageRed {}
    }
}
```

//LoaderSwitch.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

Item {
    id: loaderswitch
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    property string pageswitch

    Loader { 
        id: switchBoardLoader
        focus: true
        anchors.fill: parent
        source:"ImageBlue.qml"
        signal boardClick (string pageswitch)
        onBoardClick: {
                console.log("..method: onBoardClick..")
            if (pageswitch === "green") {
                console.log("onBoardClick = ", pageswitch)
                switchBoardLoader.source = "ImageRed.qml"}}
        onLoaded: {
            switchBoardLoader.item.showState1.connect(boardClick)}
    }
}
```

//ImageBlue.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
Item {
    id: blueItem
    width: 360
    height: 500
    property string stateSelected
    signal showState1(string stateSelected)
    Rectangle {color: "blue"; anchors.fill: parent
        Button {
            id: buttonBlue
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            text:"Green"
            onClicked: {
                stateSelected = "green"
                showState1(stateSelected)
                console.log("Blue page = ",stateSelected)}}

    }
 }
```

//ImageGreen.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

Item {
    id: greenItem
    width: 360
    height: 200
    property string stateSelected
    signal showState1(string stateSelected)
    Rectangle {color: "green"; anchors.fill: parent
        Button {
            id: buttonGreen
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            text:"Green"}
    }
 }
```

//ImageRed.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

Item {
    id: redItem
    width: 360
    height: 200
    property string stateSelected
    signal showState1(string stateSelected)
    Rectangle {color: "red"; anchors.fill: parent
        Button {
            id: buttonRed
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                text:"Green"
                onClicked: {
                    stateSelected = "green"
                    showState1(stateSelected)
                    console.log("Red page = ",stateSelected)}}
    }
 }
```

Comment: It seems that  signals within qml have boundaries.  Signals appear to propagate up the parent chain but not across chains.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem of the Loader not seeing signals from particular components by putting the components with signals that the Loader is to respond to, into the same chain.  For example

```
Chain 1 -| Loader (on Component A)
                |---- Signal (from Component B)
                |---- Signal (from Component C)
                        | -----Signal (from Component D)
```

The Loader will see all those signals because they come from children within his chain.  However, Signals from components that are not in the Loader's chain, will not be seen.

```
Chain 1 - | Loader (on Component A)
                 |---- Signal (from Component B)

Chain 2 - | Signal (from Component E)
                 | ---- Signal (from Component F)
```

The signals from Component E and F will not be seen by Loader on A.

Comment: Any example to demonstrate?